# Implementing Socket.io with ReactJS ES6

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm having trouble incorporating SocketIO client into my project as I have me project set up isomorphically. After including the socket file in my base html, I try to call `let socket = io();` in the componentdidmount of one of my components however initially after logging it in my console it is undefined. When I route to a different component and comeback to that component with that socket variable then it becomes filled with some data. I guess my point here it isn't initializing in my component what socket is, it seems like it has to wait how do I work around this?

Component.jsx

```
componentDidMount() {
    let socket = io();
    console.log(socket);
  }
```

Base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <title>TITLE</title>

    META

    LINK

</head>

<div class="app">CONTENT</div>

<!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/assets/app.js"></script>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
        var socket = io();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This works fine btw I for stuff like on connect from the server, it emits that a user is connecting and disconnecting off the server, just the client manipulation has me puzzled.

Comment: Are you using a module bundler like webpack or browserify?

Comment: Yes I am! Webpack, so should I require some kind of library?

Comment: You could import socket in your root component and, if need be, pass it down with props.https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client. here's an example from one of my projects https://github.com/zen-games/ui/blob/develop/src/components/App.js

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There are likely other solutions, but the following works for me:

1) npm install the [socket client side package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client)

2) import socket into the most root component of all components that need socket functionality

3) hookup server side socket event listeners in one of the lifecycle events (`constructor` / `componentWillMount`, `componentDidMount`)

4) pass down socket object through props if it makes sense to handle certain server events in child components

example:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
let socket = io(`http://localhost:8000`)

class App extends Component {
  state = { data: {} }

  componentDidMount() {    
    socket.on(`server:event`, data => {
      this.setState({ data })
    })
  }

  sendMessage = message => {
    socket.emit(`client:sendMessage`, message)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Child 
        socket = { socket } 
        sendMessage = { this.sendMessage }
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate a socket outside of the component and use it inside the component. Like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'  
import io from 'socket.io-client'

var socket = io()

class MyComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // You can use the socket inside the componet
        socket.on('message', msg => console.log(msg))
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same weird problem with socket.io and React. I wanted to determine a clear line of dependency injection with props to other components from my main.jsx file. Turned out that I only had to initialize io like this...

```
const socket = window.io();
```

And that was it. It worked.