# How to set socket response to react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

Whenever socket receive new data i am trying to set this data to state.
 I am creating simple chat application and i want to set this recent chat data received from socket set to state.

```
    var socket = constants.SERVER;  
    var chatData = ""

    class Chat extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { recentChat:[] }
        }


  componentDidUpdate()
  {
    socket.on(constants.SOCKET_GET_CHAT, function(data){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data))

          this.setState({
          recentChat:data
       })
    });

  }

        render() {
            return(<div/>)   
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should setState inside your socket callback, you could definetly put it in componentDidUpdate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Socket.io with ReactJS ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480703/implementing-socket-io-with-reactjs-es6)

Comment: @FabienGreard  I updated my code. I put socket inside componentDidUpdate. but i receive new error   Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Comment: Change it to an arrow function ^

Comment: you may be losing context of the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

```
 componentWillMount() {
        socket.on(constants.SOCKET_GET_CHAT, (data) => {
            this.setState({
                recentChat:data
            }) 
        });
    }
```

You have to attach listener in componentWillMount or didMount.

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.on(constants.SOCKET_GET_CHAT, data => {
  this.setState(previousState => ({
    recentChat: [...previousState.recentChat, data]
  }))
});
```

You'll want to do this as you'll constantly receive new messages from the sockets, and will want to retain the chats in this.state.recentChat and append new chats.