# TypeError while importing Socket Client with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I'm getting this error while importing the Socket into my React Component
[image: Socket Error Refernce]

I'm using  "react": "^17.0.2", and "socket.io-client": "^4.3.1" versions.

I have only added this line and it comes up with this error

[image: React Component]

I have also tried without  {   } (curly brackets) but nothing changed. I searched google a lot but all having the same king of import and works well for them. Whats going wrong for my case ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing Socket.io with ReactJS ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480703/implementing-socket-io-with-reactjs-es6)

Comment: Downgrade socket.io-client to v4.2.0 for now. The bugs introduced due to ESM builds are being resolved. It may take up to 2-3 days for the latest version to become stable enough to use.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how but deleting the node_modules folder and reinstall all packages fresh is solved my problem.